# Google Map MarkerClusterer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have a map that I've been running for awhile, just trying to added Marker Clusters since there are now enough markers on the map that it's making it difficult to see what's going on.

I don't want to change much of the coding, since everything is working as it should, but for whatever I can't figure out how to get the custom markers to cluster.

Here's Javascript coding I have for the map:

```
var marker;

function pan(latlon) {
  var coords = latlon.split(",");
  var panPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
  map.panTo(panPoint)
}

var map;

function initialize() {

  var mhbrewco = {
    lat: 50.062254,
    lng: -110.71656
  }
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.086594, -113.307591),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var BrewIcon = 'http://medicinehatbrewingcompany.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/favicon-32x32-1.png';

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: mhbrewco,
    icon: BrewIcon
  });

  var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
    '<div id="siteNotice">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Medicine Hat Brewing Company</h1>' +
    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
    '<p><b>Address:</b>' +
    ' 1366 Brier Park Dr NW' +
    ' Medicine Hat, AB T1C 1Z7</p>' +
    '<p><b>Phone:</b> <a href="tel:+14035251260">(403)525-1260</a>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.location').on('click', function() {
        map.setZoom(9);
      pan($(this).data('location'));
    });
  });

setMarkers(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

var liquorstores = [
  ['Silver Buckle Sports Bar', 50.032566, -110.665056, 1],
  ['After Work "O"asis', 50.059230, -110.669693, 2],
  ['Moxies Grill & Bar', 50.009886, -110.650260, 3],
  ['MHC Crave', 50.017578, -110.685868, 4],
  ['Cheers Neighbourhood Pub', 50.054084, -110.699307, 5],
  ['Industry Pub', 50.031567, -110.663139, 6],
  ['District Bar and Grill', 50.062417, -110.736581, 7],
  ['Mainliner Pub', 50.039407, -110.670529, 8],
  ['The Underground Tap & Grill', 53.541643, -113.490748, 9],
  ['Mauros Italian Cafe & Bar', 50.044930, -110.686023, 10],
  ['Crossroads Liquor Store', 50.024438, -110.709010, 11],
  ['Aberdeen Spirits', 50.035819, -110.676820, 12],
  ['Southwest Liquor Store', 50.032651, -110.696367, 13],
  ['Scoreboard', 50.008101, -110.646687, 14],
  ['Medicine Hat Lodge', 50.000983, -110.642278, 15],
  ['Rickys All Day Grill', 50.030527, -110.705316, 17],
  ['Beer Revolution', 53.546561, -113.523155, 18],
  ['Trackside Liquor Store', 50.030117, -110.659201, 19],
  ['Liquor Barn | Maple Avenue', 50.041581, -110.670394, 20],
  ['Liquor Barn | 3rd Street', 50.041329, -110.671092, 34],
  ['Liquor Barn | Dunmore', 50.017225, -110.658228, 35],
  ['Liquor Depot | Strachan', 49.995760, -110.643673, 36],
  ['State & Main', 50.063257, -110.688831, 22],
  ['Ralphs Texas Bar & Grill', 50.006719, -110.666115, 23],
  ['Bearded Bull', 50.037939, -110.676179, 24],
  ['Arcadia Bar', 53.556990, -113.536204, 25],
  ['Hat Liquor Store', 50.032125, -110.684876, 26],
  ['Sherbrooke Liquor Store', 53.570989, -113.548680, 27],
  ['Sobeys Cornerstone Liquor Store', 49.997892, -110.644211, 28],
  ['Northlands Co-Op Liquor Store', 50.063772, -110.685896, 29],
  ['Paul Howe Liquor Store', 50.059006, -110.669569, 30],
  ['Royal Liquor Store', 50.041701, -110.675085, 31],
  ['Ace Liquor Store', 50.062650, -110.687808, 33],
  ['Rosscos Pub', 50.0082223, -110.6462413, 34],
  ['Sierra Springs Liquor', 51.2586657, -114.0049453, 35],
  ['Brooks Liquor Store', 50.5747185, -111.9083015, 36],
  ['Brooks North End Liquor Store', 50.5747185, -111.9083015, 37],
  ['Heritage Inn & Suites', 50.5838092, -111.9008177, 38],
  ['Thirstys Cold Beer & Spirits', 50.0538104, -110.7017657, 39],
  ['Beer Revolution', 51.0431417, -114.083346, 40],
  ['Dunmore Liquor Store', 50.0118551, -110.6532196, 41],
  ['Eagle Butte Liquor Store', 49.9707704, -110.5748527, 42],
  ['The Cypress Club', 50.0402075, -110.6783379, 43],
  ['Esplanade Arts & Heritage Centre', 50.04008, -110.6834557, 44],
  ['LOCAL Public Eatery', 50.0394332, -110.677978, 45],
  ['Park Lane Cold Beer Store', 50.0325614, -110.7080837, 46],
  ['Rustic Kitchen & Bar', 50.0322693, -110.7105375, 32],
  ['South Co-Op Liquor Store', 50.0101276, -110.6650279, 47],
  ['Canex', 50.2513133, -111.1739837, 48],
  ['Bronco Billys Doll House', 50.0786134, -110.7844054, 49],
  ['Whos On 3rd', 50.0769917, -110.7872064, 50],
  ['Liquor on McLeod', 53.5439296, -113.8868955, 51],
  ['Redcliff Co-Op Liquor Store', 50.0791044,-110.780469, 52],
  ['Royal Liquor Store', 50.0414673,-110.6748202, 53],
  ['Cheesecake Cafe', 49.9958717,-110.6438655, 54]
];

function setMarkers(map) {

  var markerlink = 'http://medicinehatbrewingcompany.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/wheat-icon-marker.png';

  var markerlink = {
    url: 'http://medicinehatbrewingcompany.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/wheat-icon-marker.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
  };

  var shape = {
    coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: 'poly'
  };

  var mcMarkers = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < liquorstores.length; i++) {
    var beach = liquorstores[i];
    var barMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: beach[1],
        lng: beach[2]
      },
      map: map,
      icon: markerlink,
      shape: shape,
      title: beach[0],
      zIndex: beach[3]
    });
    mcMarkers.push(barMarker);
  };

  var mcOptions = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 15, imagePath:'/htdocs/wp-content/themes/rhythm-child/images/m'};
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, mcMarkers, mcOptions);
};
```

At this point I'm not sure if I'm just missing something... the map works, the markers are there, they just don't want to cluster.

I have the images and the markercluster.js file stored on the site's server, so that shouldn't be an issue either.

The HTML code I have calling the js files is:

```
<a name="locations"></a>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBytnwKLLyI6WBkpIltO6Qj_CaAZc_QQLI"></script>

<script src="http://www.medicinehatbrewingcompany.ca/htdocs/wp-content/themes/rhythm-child/js/markerclusterer.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are only passing 1 marker to the `markerClusterer`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add each of your markers into an array

```
// Create empty array of Markers
var markers = [];

for (var i = 0; i < liquorstores.length; i++) {
  var beach = liquorstores[i];
  var barMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: beach[1],
      lng: beach[2]
    },
    map: map,
    icon: markerlink,
    shape: shape,
    title: beach[0],
    zIndex: beach[3]
  });

  // Add marker to the array
  markers.push(barMarker);
};
```

And then pass the markers array to the Clusterer.

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I thought it could have something to do with my array not being right, but it still won't cluster.

I wondered if it was something to do with my local files, so I used the URLs from the Google Map Documentation, but that didn't work either.

Comment: You did it obviously wrong. Look again at my answer and your code edit. Learn how to indent your code, it might help.

Comment: Obviously I did it wrong, which is why I'm reaching out for help. I did notice the 'markers.push(barMarker);' was in a different place than where you had it. I highly doubt it's the indenting, I'm having issues formatting correctly here. 

Apologies for being a bother, thanks again for your help.

Comment: I am not saying the indenting is the problem. Code doesn't *need* to be indented but it just helps you to identify what is where. If this helped, kindly upvote/approve the answer, that's how it works here.